# Is putting an Angular frontend into a seperate source control repo considered good practice?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git

I am developing a web application with an API written with Node and an Angular frontend. My current deployment pipeline watches source control for changes and then pushes everything to a build server, where it is built and then deployed into production. Currently, my Node application is set to serve the Angular frontend, which is unnecessary and needs changed. My question is, would it be a good idea to place the front and backend applications into different repos? That way, I can control the deployment of each on individually. My Node app uses a lot of C++ libraries that take some time to compile, and I don't want to have to compile them every time I make a change to the frontend. Is it a good idea to separate them?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid re-compiling back-end libraries when you change your front-end code, you don't need to separate repos.
Some rule in your gulp/grunt/whatever config should suffice...